# Facebook SDK for IOS, Swift - Using Multiple Targets, different bundle identifiers, etc

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

In xCode, I have a project which uses multiple targets and each target has specific bundle name, bundle identifiers and so on. The reason being the client wants to re-use the layouts and this can't be changed since we have reached so far in the project.

I need to integrate Facebook login for each target but it is only working for the initial target since it still has the default 'Info.plist' file-name.

When I try to login using the other target, I get different errors but all relating to the fact that the SDK is still reading the information in the 'Info.plist'. For example:

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fb********** is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'**

Can you please advice me how can I tell the sdk to read a different plist file for each targets?

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution which was already answered on SO.

The thing is to use user defined settings and to reference them in the info.plist file.